# Correction for multiple comparisons using sum contrasts with linear regression

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, linear-model, contrasts

I am computing the following model using the lme4 package in R:

```
score ~ expertise*(mood + condition + course) **(EDIT: + (1|participant))**

Outcome:
score / numeric (1-7)

Inputs:
expertise / factor (NOVice, expert)
condition / factor (ALOne, together)
mood / numeric (1-7)
course / factor (YES, NO)
```

All the factors are coded using sum contrasts. The result looks like this:

```
        Predictor                             b          Std.Er  df    
        (Intercept)                           1.52941    0.22044 152.36196   6.938 1.07e-10 ***
        expertiseNOV                         -0.26262    0.22044 152.36196  -1.191  0.23539    
        condALO                               0.02033    0.03133 710.39747   0.649  0.51666    
        mood                                  0.31964    0.03153 744.54866  10.137  < 2e-16 ***
        courseYES                            -0.07763    0.10865 417.97130  -0.714  0.47533    
        expertiseNOV:condALO                 -0.17815    0.03133 710.39747  -5.686 1.90e-08 ***
        expertiseNOV:mood                     0.09947    0.03153 744.54866   3.154  0.00167 ** 
        expertiseNOV:courseYES                0.12540    0.10865 417.97130   1.154  0.24908
```

If I interpret this model correctly, expertiseNOV to courseYES should be the main effects at the average level of the other predictors. Furthermore, the interaction "expertiseNOV:condALO" is for example telling me that there is a significant difference between experts and novices for the condition "alone". I now would like to know if there is also a significant difference for the condition "together". I could now reorder the factors and get the results for the following interaction: "expertiseNOV:condTOG"

Would I then need to correct my results for multiple comparisons? Or is this just the wrong way to approach this issue?

**EDIT 04.10.2022**

As I assigned the contrast schemes manually, I seem to have made a small mistake when assigning the names for the factor "condition". Here is the complete procedure I am using based on simulated data as proposed by @dipetkov. The code features one model using treatment contrasts and one using sum contrasts.
set.seed(1234)

```
n <- 100

data <- data.frame(
  expertise = sample(c("NOV", "EXP"), n, replace = TRUE),
  cond = sample(c("ALO", "TOG"), n, replace = TRUE),
  course = sample(c("YES", "NO"), n, replace = TRUE),
  mood = sample(seq(7), n, replace = TRUE),
  score = rnorm(n)
)

data <- data %>% mutate(
  expertise = as.factor(expertise),
  cond = as.factor(cond),
  course = as.factor(course),
)

#sum contrasts
contr_sum <- contr.sum(2)
colnames(contr_sum) <- c("NOV")
contrasts(data$expertise) <- contr_sum

colnames(contr_sum) <- c("TOG")
contrasts(data$cond) <- contr_sum

colnames(contr_sum) <- c("YES")
contrasts(data$course) <- contr_sum

model_sum <- lm(
  score ~ expertise * (mood + cond + course),
  data = data
)

summary(model_sum)

#treatment contrasts
contr_treatment <- contr.treatment(2)
colnames(contr_treatment) <- c("NOV")
contrasts(data$expertise) <- contr_treatment

colnames(contr_treatment) <- c("TOG")
contrasts(data$cond) <- contr_treatment

colnames(contr_treatment) <- c("YES")
contrasts(data$course) <- contr_treatment

model_trea <- lm(
  score ~ expertise * (mood + cond + course),
  data = data
)

summary(model_trea)
```

Output model_sum:

```
Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)             0.09177    0.23428   0.392    0.696
expertiseNOV            0.28286    0.23428   1.207    0.230
mood                    0.01672    0.05225   0.320    0.750
condTOG                 0.03264    0.10073   0.324    0.747
courseYES               0.15819    0.10194   1.552    0.124
expertiseNOV:mood      -0.06743    0.05225  -1.290    0.200
expertiseNOV:condTOG    0.06188    0.10073   0.614    0.541
expertiseNOV:courseYES -0.04754    0.10194  -0.466    0.642
```

Output model_trea:

```
Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)             0.57980    0.41055   1.412    0.161
expertiseNOV           -0.59440    0.60245  -0.987    0.326
mood                   -0.05071    0.06741  -0.752    0.454
condTOG                -0.18903    0.26240  -0.720    0.473
courseYES              -0.22131    0.26476  -0.836    0.405
expertiseNOV:mood       0.13485    0.10451   1.290    0.200
expertiseNOV:condTOG    0.24750    0.40291   0.614    0.541
expertiseNOV:courseYES -0.19014    0.40774  -0.466    0.642
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you use the `lme4` package (designed for fitting mixed-effects models) but your model formula seems to have fixed effects only. How come?

> expertiseNOV to courseYES should be the main effects at the average level of the other predictors

This is wrong. We know (from the naming convention used in the summary table) that the model is fitted with the treatment coding, which is the default in R. The intercept corresponds to:

```
(expertise, condition, mood, course) = (expert, together, 0, NO)
```

> the interaction "expertiseNOV:condALO" is for example telling me that there is a significant difference between experts and novices for the condition "alone"

Actually, it's telling you that there is a significant interaction between expertise and condition. Since expertise is interacted with mood and course as well, the interpretation of the interaction terms is a bit more involved. `expertiseNOV:condALO` is the expected difference in score between novices and experts when `mood=0` and `course="NO"`. (Substitute either `mood>0` and/or `course="YES"`, to see how the other two interactions contribute to the expected difference as well.)

So what to do? Learn about contrasts and how to use them to make the post-hoc comparisons that you'd like to make.

A popular package for post-hoc comparisons is [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html). I generate fake data to illustrate how to use it (that code is attached at the end) but the best place to start is to read the vignettes.

```r
# Not the same summary table since you don't provide your data.
#> Coefficients:
#>                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)             0.57980    0.41055   1.412    0.161
#> expertiseNOV           -0.59440    0.60245  -0.987    0.326
#> mood                   -0.05071    0.06741  -0.752    0.454
#> condTOG                -0.18903    0.26240  -0.720    0.473
#> courseYES              -0.22131    0.26476  -0.836    0.405
#> expertiseNOV:mood       0.13485    0.10451   1.290    0.200
#> expertiseNOV:condTOG    0.24750    0.40291   0.614    0.541
#> expertiseNOV:courseYES -0.19014    0.40774  -0.466    0.642
```

Making post-hoc comparisons in a model with multiple interactions is not equivalent to looking at individual regression coefficients.

```r
library("emmeans")

pairs(emmeans(model, ~ expertise | cond))
#> cond = ALO:
#>  contrast  estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  EXP - NOV    0.139 0.287 92   0.485  0.6288
#> 
#> cond = TOG:
#>  contrast  estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  EXP - NOV   -0.108 0.284 92  -0.381  0.7037
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: course
```

You can also use the [contrast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contrast/index.html) package to specify the comparisons you want to make as contrasts. (Be careful loading `contrast` and `emmeans` at the same time. They both define a `contrast` function.)

Let's reproduce the `emmeans` output for the comparison between expert and novices when the condition is "together". We set (condition, moon, course) = ("TOG", average mood, either "YES" or "NO")`.

```r
library("contrast")

contrast(
  model,
  list(expertise = "EXP", cond = "TOG", mood = mean(data$mood), course = c("YES", "NO")),
  list(expertise = "NOV", cond = "TOG", mood = mean(data$mood), course = c("YES", "NO")),
  type = "average"
)
#>     contrast
#> lm model parameter contrast
#> 
#>     Contrast     S.E.     Lower     Upper     t df Pr(>|t|)
#> 1 -0.1082324 0.283703 -0.671691 0.4552262 -0.38 92   0.7037
```

If we choose a different mood setting, the contrast between the two expertise levels changes because of the expertise-mood interaction.

```r
contrast(
  model,
  list(expertise = "EXP", cond = "TOG", mood = 7, course = c("YES", "NO")),
  list(expertise = "NOV", cond = "TOG", mood = 7, course = c("YES", "NO")),
  type = "average"
)
#> lm model parameter contrast
#> 
#>     Contrast      S.E.     Lower     Upper     t df Pr(>|t|)
#> 1 -0.5019994 0.4301315 -1.356278 0.3522789 -1.17 92   0.2462
```

And if you are not interested in a particular mood, you may prefer to visualize the expected score differences between experts and novices for all combinations of course and condition as a function of mood. This can be done quickly with the [ggeffects](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/index.html) package.

```r
library("ggeffects")

plot(
  ggemmeans(model, terms = c("mood [1:7]", "course", "expertise", "cond"))
)
```

[image]

In short, multiple interactions make post-hoc comparisons more complex and more fun.

---

The R code used to simulate data for illustration purposes.

```r
set.seed(1234)

n <- 100

data <- data.frame(
  expertise = sample(c("NOV", "EXP"), n, replace = TRUE),
  cond = sample(c("ALO", "TOG"), n, replace = TRUE),
  course = sample(c("YES", "NO"), n, replace = TRUE),
  mood = sample(seq(7), n, replace = TRUE),
  score = rnorm(n)
)

model <- lm(
  score ~ expertise * (mood + cond + course),
  data = data
)
```

Comment: Thanks @dipetkov for you detailed reply. You are completely right in that I forgot the varying intercept in my initial post. As mentioned in the edit above, I actually used sum contrasts, I just made a mistake when naming one of the factors.  I would still be interested in also clarifying my initial question if I could just reorder the factors to run an additional comparison using sum contrasts. (So not only the interaction for "expertiseNOV:condTog", but "expertiseNOV:condALO" in my second model.)

Comment: A couple of small details in my answer are now irrelevant (and I update later). But the gist remains: one interaction term on its own is not meaningful to interpret because there are other interactions in the model. When you vary mood you change several terms in the model at the same time. You should use contrasts instead. They don't depend on the encoding/parametrization. So much easier to interpret. And explain actually.

Comment: The encoding (treatment or sum) doesn't change the model. So the inference (statistical conclusions) are exactly the same, no matter what the parametrization is.

Comment: I don't exactly understand where the difference lies for you between encoding and contrasts. As far as I know, contrasts can be directly used to test hypothesis ( https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749596X19300695).

Setting different contrasts (Treatment / Sum) changes the interpretation of the coefficients. Treatment coding gives you simple effects (at the base level of all other factors), sum contr. give you main effects (at the avg. level of the other factors).

I agree that one can also calculate marginal effects instead, but how could I solve it without?

Comment: Solve what? I'm not sure we have the same definition of contrasts. For me "treatment" / "sum" are two different parametrizations. While a contrast is a comparison, eg., the difference between novices and expert when the rest of the predictors are either fixed at specific values or averaged out. Whether the model uses the treatment or the sum parameterization, the comparison between novices and experts would be the same. Note: R confusingly refers to parametrization as "contrast coding".

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I agree that a post-hoc calculated contrast will be the same independent of the parametrization of the model. But the parametrization of the model will change how the coefficients can be interpreted. The coefficient expertiseNOV tells us if there is a significant difference between expertise groups at the average level of all the other factors(with sum contrasts). So I do not need calculate a contrast for this anymore. However, due to the parametrization and factor ordering some comparisons are not directly displayed in the coefficients.

Comment: By reordering the factors I would know change the parametrization again, showing a coefficient which would allow further inferences about the differences (in my case the interaction). 

However, it is unclear if such new parametrizations also require a quasi "multi-comparison" correction.

Comment: You change the parametrization, but not the model, and therefore not the inference. Statistically, you change nothing. That's why interpreting the regression coefficients directly can end up being not especially meaningful. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: The main reason is that by interpreting the models parameters directly I do not need to run post-hoc comparisons for which I need to calculate corrections, which reduce the power of these tests.

Comment: I think you do. You want to make a statement about the difference between expert and novices for each of the conditions. You can't ignore the other factors, however, because of the multiple interactions. You have to decide whether to fix mood and course at a specific level or to marginalize them out. You have to think about that and the best approach is contrasts. The interaction terms in the summary table are at mood = 0 (since mood is numeric). It's not even one of the possible mood levels, so  the "raw" interaction is not particularly interpretable. (You can rescale mood I guess....)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get the point. Even after rescaling the interpretation of the correlation coefficients is hard. So it is definitely a good idea to estimate marginal means.